# traverse a unordered binary tree

Tags: tree, parallel-processing

I have a situation where I need to access tree in parallel fashion.
How is it possible? I am unable to think of anything in trees without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer on this but I thought other people might benefit.

You can still use recursion but you need to lock branches of the tree and allow other threads to 'skip' those branches because they are already being (or already have been) processed.

For example, lets say you are processing a tree doing a breadth first traversal so at each run of the recursive method you iterate through the children of the current node.  Each thread must iterate through the children of the current node and try to lock each child node, skipping it if it is already locked.

I'm not sure what tree implementation you are using so you should treat the 'Node' object in the following example code as pseudocode, but the rest is correct Java.

In the example below a predetermined depth is picked to apply locking at - this ensures that the threads don't simply lock at the root of the tree and serialise access to the entire tree.

Choice of the correct depth would depend on the shape of your particular tree.  For example if its a binary tree then your tree might have up to 8 branches at depth 3, which would be most likely be fine for a couple of threads, but if you were running 20 threads you would need to pick a point of serialisation of lower depth to ensure that all threads were able to process some branch.

You could also use some other method of deciding when to lock (e.g. if the node could efficiently report on how many leaf nodes it had you could set a threshold on that), the important thing is that all threads use the same code for making the decision to lock or not to lock.

```
Object master_LOCK = new Object();
HashMap locks = new HashMap();
int DEPTH = 5;

public boolean lockNode(Object nodeID) {
    synchronized(master_LOCK) {
        Object node_LOCK = (Object)locks.get(nodeID);
        if (node_LOCK == null) {
            //we can lock this node
            locks.put(nodeID,new Object());
            return true;
        } else {
            //node already locked
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public void traverseBreadhFirst(Node node) {    
    locks.clear();
    traverseBreadthFirst(node,0);
}

public void traverseBreadthFirst(Node node, int currentDepth) {
    currentDepth++;

    //Process the current node here


    //Iterate through children, locking to force serialised access only at a predetermined depth
    List children = node.getChildren();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {

        Node child = (Node)children.get(i);

        //If we are a certain depth in the tree we start serialising access from that point on
        //This ensures that there are enough branches at this point to roughly evenly distribute them 
        //to all available threads.

        if (currentDepth < DEPTH ) {
            //All threads are to go to depth N
            traverseBreadthFirst(node,currentDepth);

        } else if (currentDepth == DEPTH ) {
            //At depth N we lock all branches we intend to process
            if (lockNode(child.getID())) {
                //We have locked this child node so we should process it
                traverseBreadthFirst(node,currentDepth);
            } else {
                //This child has been locked for processing already so we skip it
            }

        } else {
            //We are deeper than depth N so we can traverse our locked branch without locking further
            traverseBreadthFirst(node,currentDepth);

        }
    }

}
```